# SQLike query on JSON returning 3996 objects

Tags: javascript, json, sqlike

I am trying to query a JSON object in order to determine a username. However, when I run the SQLike i have 3996 objects returned, none of which matching the correct parameters that I have asked to be returned. Would anyone be able to point out where I have gone wrong and as to why I am receiving 3996 returned objects and further, how can I strip it out to only return a username?

**user.json**

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "fName": "Sam",
        "lName": "Street",
        "username": "sam",
        "password": "123"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "fName": "Matt",
        "lName": "Mantle",
        "username": "matt",
        "password": "123"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "fName": "Dev",
        "lName": "Mode",
        "username": "dev",
        "password": "123"
    }
]
```

The javascript that I call on a submit of a form

```
$("#login_form").submit(function (e) {
    // prevent default action
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var username = form.find("#username").val();
    var password = form.find("#password").val();

    // need to pass this as generic function when finished
    var userData = $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'user.json',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

    var sel = SQLike.q(
        {
            Select: ['*'],
            From: userData,
            Where: function () { return this.userData = username }
        }
    )
    console.log(sel);
});
```

Comment: It appears that you'll be going to check the password client-side. Don't do that.

Comment: Hm, just to be sure: `return this.userData = username` <-- are you sure this is `=` and not `==`?

Comment: @bouke - I am not doing any log in or anything along those lines, this is purely for learning purposes as I just wanted to learn how to query a JSON file.

@fge - I have used `return this.userData = username` and not `return this.userData == username`

Comment: Well, do use `==`... Here you affect `username` to `this.userdata`; the result of the function will always be true (unless `username` is empty or null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Consider this a "partial" answer because I am not familiar with that library; I'm merely going off of their documentation.*

Ajax is normally asynchronous, and I wouldn't recommend making it synchronous.

The `$.ajax` returns the [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR); it is not the JSON data you're expecting to get.

To make life easier, I would move your `SQLike` code in to the success function of the ajax call, like so:

```
// need to pass this as generic function when finished
var userData = $.ajax({
    url: 'user.json',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var sel = SQLike.q(
        {
            Select: ['*'],
            From: data,
            Where: function () { return this.data === username }
        }
    }
});
```

Note the non-assignment equals `===` already explained by epascarello.

Now for the "partial" answer portion: while I'm not familiar with this library, looking through their documentation makes me wonder if your `Where` function should look like this:

```
return this.username === username
```

Or something along those lines. From what I'm seeing, the `Where` would be called to filter rows (as expected), and the `this` context would be the current object to be filtered.

Answer (score 2):

```
return this.userData = username
                    ^^^
```

`=` is assignment and since you are returning an assignment it will be true and every record will be returned.

```
return this.userData === username;
                     ^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the error pointed out by epascarello, you'd also want to check the value of `'username'`, not `'userData'`:

```
return this['username'] === username;
```